# How to create Google Wave-like scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make the scrollbars like in Google Wave?
They save a lot of space and look nice.I would like to put the scrollbars on a div like how google wave does it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mikeabundo.com](http://cdn.mikeabundo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/google-wave.gif))</sub>

Comment: You should, if you legally can, post a screenshot demonstrating what you're referring to. Not all of us have Google Wave accounts! ;)

Comment: Wave was a GWT project, so you might find interesting widgets there. (Disclaimer: I've never used GWT :-)

Comment: LOL. You opened Up all your account details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a custom element ( maybe a div ) that acts like a scroll bar.

You can find a number of implementation using jQuery

[jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/examples.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here http://jebaird.com/blog/shortscroll-jquery-ui-google-wave-style-scroll-bar, it is similar but has not all Google Wave functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you pretty close:
http://konrness.com/javascript/google-wave-style-scroll-bar-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation using JQuery: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ftyr6mg8vwa6k4/gWaveScrollbar%20plugin.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Links are not appropriate answers - what if your link dies?  Please post the essential parts of the link into your answer.

Comment: Changed the link to archive